# How do I calculate the revenue generated from taking customers from another business?

Tags: sql

I have 2 years worth of data on customers where they each buy a product (A, B, C, etc) from retailer (1,2,3, etc). Hypothetically, my business is retailer 2. I want to calculate the revenue if the same product is purchased from retailer 1 only if it is later purchased from business 2. The customer also must have purchased from another business to be counted.

Columns available: Customer_ID, Product, Date_of_Purchase, Business_ID, Price

SQL:

```sql
select sum(price), customer_id, product, date_of_purchase, business_id
from customerdata
 ???
group by business_id
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text (not images, not links.) I.e. a [mcve]. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bs_2.customer_id, bs_2.product, bs_2.date_of_purchase, bs_2.price
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM customerdata
      WHERE business_id = 2) AS bs_2
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM customerdata
            WHERE business_id <> 2) AS cmpt -- competition
ON bs_2.customer_id= cmpt.customer_id
   AND bs_2.product = cmpt.product
   AND bs_2.date_of_purchase > cmpt.date_of_purchase
```

This query retrieves customers that bought from business 2 (your business) and also bought the same product earlier from another supplier.

Once you have that, you can aggregate it however you like.

- I presume we don't have the same customer buying the same product at the same price on the same date from the same retailer...